# beautifulsoup is not working on a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features="lxml")
x = soup.find("div",{"class":"innerp product-box  Even  product_300564"})
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the website is loaded via javascript. Try using selenium instead of Beautifulsoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan")

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.innerp.product-box.Even.product_300564')
print(element.text)


>>> element.text
'Samsung Galaxy A51 (4G, 6GB, 128GB, Prism Black) With Official Warranty\nRs 53,999'
```

Comment: but why beautifull soup is not doing it?

Comment: Beautifulsoup is doing it.  Please see my answer -  I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You had it right, but just remove the extra spaces before and after Even in the class definition.
Like this:

```
x = soup.find("div",{"class":"innerp product-box Even product_300564"})
```

You may have copied the class definition just like that from the html, but it seems Beautifulsoup prettified it not to contain spaces.